# Using a Servo motor as load on a system

Tags: motor, servo, load

Can a Servo motor (or any electric motor) be used as a load on a system ? meaning can it reprisent for example a certain dead weight ?

In the picture below you can see a motor driving 3 gears, to apply a certain load on the system could i put another motor on the other end ? will that burn the motor ? how would the load be applied should the second motor receive current ? or run in reverse ?
[image: System]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geared servo motors generally do not like being run in reverse. You may damage the geartrain. Simple DC motors are better for that, although not at low speed. Connect a power resistor across the terminals and it will dump energy from the shaft speed into the resistor.

You might be better off with a mechanical friction brake of some kind. Or dump the energy into a fluid. A set of paddles rotating in the air is a common small test load. For lower speeds and higher torque, put a paddle in a liquid such as water or oil.

Comment: from a mechanical point of view I was actually expecting that the geatrain might get damage. do you think dc motors can provide sufficient load or are you just suggesting conecting it to the rotating paddles ?

Comment: I have no idea how fast the system is or what level of load torque you want - define "sufficient"!

Comment: the driving mototr has a Stall Torque of 37.7 kg·cm
i was looking for a way to apply load around 5 to 10 kg via the shaft on the side (not the one where the motor is connected )

Answer (score 0):

If the electromechanical device outputs positive torque, then it is called motor, if it outputs negative torque, then it is called a generator. Both modes exist in a electromechanical device at the same time. Threfore if you spin the gears wit a servomotor and you mount a second servomotor that has as setpoint negative torque, then the second one will act as a generator.The energy generated has to be dumped trough a braking resitor, regenerative power suplly unit or the two devices could share the same DC bus, in that condition the energy would circulate.